# C# WPF ViewModel for a class with List

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a class with a list of items, something like this:

```
public class Model{
    List<int> Items { get; set; }
}
```

It uses List, not ObservableCollection, and doesn't have any events to be subscribed to.
I need to make a ListBox oneway-bound to this list and a way to remove items one-by-one. So I must write a ViewModel class, a property of which can be oneway-bound to ListBox to show these items and to update the ListBox when the list is changed with RemoveItem method. I don't know how to oneway bind ListBox to this List. If I make a ViewModel class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged the same way I do for string property and a textbox, it doesn't work.
Please teach me how to do this without changing the Model class.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a property in the view model that is `ObservableCollection` and initialize it with the list from the model.

The view model will implement the 'removeFromList' method where it will remove an item from the `ObservableCollection` property (the view model's property) and afterwards you will remove the same item from the list in the model.